# Add files to git when directory already added

Tags: git

I know this is strange, because git shouldn't keep empty directories. This is what I did:

```
git add directory
git commit
```

In `directory` there are files, which I also want to add, but only some of them. However, none files were added, and I can't add any now.

When I clone repository to different location, I can clearly see that `directory` is empty.

When I try to add file in `directory` to git like this:

```
git add directory/file
```

I get an error `fatal: Path 'directory/file' is in submodule 'directory'`

How can I add this files?

Answer (score 5):

This is not an empty directory, this is a submodule. Read [ProGit: Submodules](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html) and [man git-submoule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) on how to handle them.

Especially: If you clone a repository with submodules, you should init the submodules too

```
# git clone ...
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is a submodule. The empty directory needs to be in the containing (parent) repo. The submodule has it's own clone url.

On the clone, issue

```
git submodule update --init
```

And you're good to go (provided you have access to the clone url of the submodule)

Comment: I think it's confusing to refer to a repository as "master", given its standard use for your main branch in git :)  Also, in the cloned repository you need to do `git submodule update --init` or you'll get an error saying the submodule hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Ah, I do this not often enough to remember the init; I bet it's something that the `update` will tell me everytime :)